# Custom WPF Databinding

Tags: wpf, data-binding

I have a List of DataItem's.

DataItem has a RowId, ColumnId and Value.

These dataitems essentially describe the contents of a user definable "table".

Now I need to bind this data to a datagrid in such a way that it represents the "table". i.e. the DataItem Value's should be displayed in a grid using their RowId and ColumnId.

Any help with this binding problem would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use binding, you'll need an `ItemsControl`, like `ListBox` and modify its `ItemsPanelTemplate` to use `Grid`. If you don't know the number of columns and rows, unfortunately you'll have to generate them manually from code. Or implement your own `Panel` completely.

Here's the sample. You'll have to change all bindings from XPath if your underlying model is not XML.

```
<Window x:Class="CoordBinding.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">

    <Window.Resources>
        <XmlDataProvider x:Key="_items">
            <x:XData>
                <Items xmlns="">
                    <Item ColId="1" RowId="2">Blah</Item>
                    <Item ColId="0" RowId="1">Doh</Item>
                    <Item ColId="2" RowId="0">Meh</Item>
                </Items>
            </x:XData>
        </XmlDataProvider>
    </Window.Resources>

    <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource _items},XPath=Items/*}">
        <ListBox.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                <Grid IsItemsHost="True">
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition/>
                        <ColumnDefinition/>
                        <ColumnDefinition/>
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <RowDefinition/>
                        <RowDefinition/>
                        <RowDefinition/>
                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                </Grid>
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemsPanel>

        <ListBox.Resources>
            <Style TargetType="ListBoxItem">
                <Setter Property="Grid.Row" Value="{Binding XPath=@RowId}" />
                <Setter Property="Grid.Column" Value="{Binding XPath=@ColId}" />
            </Style>
        </ListBox.Resources>

    </ListBox>

</Window>
```

Answer (score 0):

OK, this might not be the most "ideal" method (I'd prefer to get it going in XAML), but here's something to get you started.  This code starts with a List called Items, and a Grid declared with the name ItemsGrid.

```
        int maxRow = Items.Select(i => i.RowId).Max();
        int maxCol = Items.Select(i => i.ColumnId).Max();

        for (int i = 0; i <= maxRow; i++)
            ItemsGrid.RowDefinitions.Add(new RowDefinition());

        for (int i = 0; i <= maxCol; i++)
            ItemsGrid.ColumnDefinitions.Add(new ColumnDefinition());

        foreach (var item in Items)
        {
            TextBlock newItem = new TextBlock() { Text = item.Value };
            ItemsGrid.Children.Add(newItem);
            Grid.SetRow(newItem, item.RowId);
            Grid.SetColumn(newItem, item.ColumnId);
        }
```

Alternatively, you could look into actual DataGrid controls outside of what's cooked into the .NET Framework right now.

The WPF Toolkit has a DataGrid that I've used successfully on several projects:
http://wpf.codeplex.com/Release/ProjectReleases.aspx?ReleaseId=29117

Third-party vendors also produce simimlar grids.  Prominent ones, in no particular order, are Xceed, Telerik, Infragistics, and Syncfusion.

Hope that helps!
Tim